# What is right way to display a detail view?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, detailview

I'm new to iOS, coming from a PHP/MYSQL background, and am trying to show a detail view of a table.

I have created a simple NSMutableArray to hold some records as we say in web programming. I am able to display these in a table view and have it working so when you touch a row, you go to the detail page.

But I am totally flummoxed by how you get the detail view to display data using the MVC model and have scoured the web to no avail trying to find a simple example how to do this. I have tried numerous tutorials and viewed numerous videos but can't get the hang of it, because I don't understand the principle involved.  I want to pull the data for the record clicked on, but don't know to pass this to the detail view.

The NSMutableArray is created in the tableview controller.  Trying to follow MVC, I have also created a model class that lists some properties corresponding to the field names held in the array.

What I can't figure out is how to display this in the detail view.

Does it have something to do with Prepare for Segue?  However, that would seem to violate MVC as the data for the detail page is actually in the table view page i.e. a different controllers.

I'm desperate for some guidance...

I don't know what code to try as none has worked for me. I just need a basic example of how to do this seemingly simple routine task.

Answer (score 0):

Create a property in your DetailViewController then set the property in your TableViewController's as follows in its 'didSelectRowAtIndexPath'

```
DetailViewController *dvc = [DetailViewController alloc] init]; //Can be instantiated via the storyboard too.
```

OR

```
DetailViewController *dvc = (DetailViewController *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailViewControllerIdentifier"]; // Do not forget to set the identifier in the storyboard for the viewcontroller.
```

then,

```
dvc.recordsArray = self.recordsArray //setting the recordsArray property of the DetailViewController object to point to the TableViewController recordsArray

[self.navigationController pushViewController:DVC animated:YES];

[self.TableViewController deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
```

Comment: This does not use prepareforsegue that tutorials all seem to recommend.  Is that unnecessary?

Comment: You can use prepareForSegue if you are performing the navigation through your segues either from the storyboard or through the code using performSegueWithIdentifier [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SegueIdentifier" sender:self];
 . You can alternatively do the above when you are pushing a view controller when selecting a particular element.